# Export table as excel in php

Tags: php, jquery, html

My table has input type text inside td of table, i am getting blank values.Using jquery.table2excel.js to export table. 
Here is the sample code

```
<tr>
    <td class="DG_table">
       <span class="left">Total Revenue ($)</span>
    </td>
    <td class="DG_table">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" value="2779695.009431"/>
    </td>
    <td class="DG_table">
       <input class="form-control" type="text" value="2779695.009431"/>
    </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: use PHPExcel library

Comment: The problem is client wants to edit the value and get the excel on fly.

Comment: No problem you can also achieved with this library ,you can generate excel on the fly https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options, you can convert your data to a CSV, or use the [PHPExcel Library](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

You can put your data into arrays and use the [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function.

**CSV Example**

```
$data = array (
    array('row 1 col 1', 'row 1 col 2', 'row 1 col 3'),
    array('row 2 col 1', 'row 2 col 2', 'row 2 col 3'),
    array('row 3 col 1', 'row 3 col 2', 'row 3 col 3'),
);


$file = fopen('mycsv.csv', 'w');

foreach ($data as $cells) {
    fputcsv($file, $cells);
}
fclose($file);
```